# username validation and login in django

Tags: django, validation, django-models

I'm trying to validate the username whether it is present in the database or not? If it is there it should show validation error and if not there it should proceed to next step. But my code is not working.And login is also not working if i give the registered username and password it is not taking.I don't know where I'm wrong.I'm a newbie to this .Anyone plz help. Thanks in advance.

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from .models import Core
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Registrationform(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=15, label="Username")
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=15,label="Firstname")
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=15,label="Lastname")
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, 
   label="Password")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, 
   label="PasswordConfirmation")

    class Meta:
        model = Core
        fields = ("username", "firstname", "lastname", "email", 
     "password", "password1",)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        username_qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if username_qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError("Username already exists")
        return username

    def clean_password1(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        if password and password1 and password != password1:
            raise ValidationError("Password did n't match")
        return password1

  class login_form(forms.Form):
          username = forms.CharField()
         password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

      def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
         username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
         password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
         if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
               raise forms.ValidationError("Username does not exists")
            if user.checkpassword(password):
               raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Password")
            return render(request, 'invalid.html')
```

model.py

```
  from django.db import models
   class Core(models.Model):
         username = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
         firstname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
         lastname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
         email = models.EmailField()
         password = models.CharField(max_length=8)
         password1 = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

views.py

```
      from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
      from .form import Registrationform
      from .form import login_form
      from django.contrib import messages
      from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
      from django.contrib import auth


def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')



def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = Registrationform(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          messages.success(request,'Registration Successfull')
       return redirect('home')

else:
    form = Registrationform()

return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


def login(request):
    form = login_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
       username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
       password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
       login(request,user)
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You could just use the django inbuilt registration form which is made for that. I would suggest a different approche, check the input with ajax while the user is typing the name and tell him directly if the username exists

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel! Set `username` in your model to `unique=True`, if not already done.

Comment: @hansTheFranz Thanks for the very helpful comment. It is a general beginner error to reinvent everything the framework already offers. The key point of using a framework is not to implement your own user authentication.

Comment: @hansTheFranz, Thanks ! I want to use my own form.where username validation is not working

Comment: @cezar,I did unique=True in model and i got error statement,but the problem is I'm getting like this with app name -Core with this Username already exists.I just want to display Username already exists.Kindly help me

Comment: What you (think you) want and what you really need are two different things. If you want to listen to me, then check the [documentation about authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/). You can find also about authentication views. Everything is there, no need to reinvent the wheel. When you use a framework, concentrate yourself on your actual problem.

Comment: @cezar.I went through that document .but i'm sorry i didn't get anything.I want my username to raise error when it is there in the database already ,as username already exists.Can you help me

Comment: We can't help you with the provided information. The code looks ok and we can't reproduce any error. Again, think about using the inbuilt `UserCreationForm`. Check also this [blog](https://overiq.com/django/1.10/django-creating-users-using-usercreationform/).

Comment: What do you have in the model `Core`? Can you show it us? Eventually there might be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In `clean_username` use:

`raise forms.ValidationError('error message')`

instead of `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError`.

This will return an error in `form.errors` instead of raising an exception.

Comment: again it is working only for password not for username